# Como fazer uma query recursiva com as relações armazenadas num JSON array?

Tags: mysql, json, query, recursão

Eu tenho uma tabela MYSQL que se relaciona com ela mesma. As relações estao representadas na mesma tabela através dum `JSON Array`. Eis a tabela e alguns dados de exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `templatedata` (
  `Id` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `RelatesWith` json DEFAULT NULL
);

insert into templatedata values
('1', JSON_ARRAY('2')),
('2', JSON_ARRAY('3')),
('3', JSON_ARRAY('4')),
('4', JSON_ARRAY()),
('5', JSON_ARRAY('6', '7')),
('6', JSON_ARRAY()),
('7', JSON_ARRAY('8')),
('8', JSON_ARRAY());
```

Aquilo que estou a tentar fazer é obter todas as relações para um determinado id. Por exemplo o id 1 relaciona com `2, 3, 4`. Enquanto o id 5 relaciona com `6, 7, 8`. E o 7 apenas com 8, etc...

Eu consegui obter o primeiro nível de relações com a seguinte query:

```
With recursive cte (id, relatesWith, level) AS
(
    select id, relatesWith, 0 as level from templatedata

    union    

    select cte.id, JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(cte.relatesWith, templatedata.relatesWith), level+1  from cte
    join templatedata on JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_ARRAY(templatedata.Id), cte.RelatesWith)
    where JSON_LENGTH(templatedata.relatesWith) <> 0 and JSON_LENGTH(cte.relatesWith) <> 0 
)
SELECT cte.* FROM cte;
```

Mas estou com dificuldade em obter os restantes. Como posso obter todas as relações, como desejo.

[SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uGtdt92t7A8b7uzQdPkpY6/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query estava quase certa. Contudo é necessário ter cuidado para escrever a segunda query de forma precisa, quer no `select`, quer no `join`. No `select` é necessário escolher as colunas de forma a que a recursão de certo. E evidentemente no `join` é necessário escolher a condição adequada para a recursão. Aqui fica a query corrigida.

```
With recursive cte (id, relatesWith, level) AS
(
    select id, relatesWith, 0 as level from templatedata
    where JSON_LENGTH(templatedata.relatesWith) = 0

    union    

    select t.id, JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(cte.relatesWith, t.relatesWith), level+1  from cte
    join templatedata t on JSON_CONTAINS(t.RelatesWith, JSON_ARRAY(cte.Id))
)
SELECT cte.* FROM cte;
```